# Remove everything before (including) the last occurence of a character

Tags: regex

Please help me get everything after the last occurrence of `/` using regex.
My variables look like this:

```
http://domain.com/folder/subfolder/123456
http://domain.com/folder/subfolder/678901
etc.
```

and I only need the part after the last `/`
i.e.

```
123456
678901
```

Currently I'm using `/[^/]*$` but this gives me `/123456` & `/678901`.

Comment: which flavor????????????

Comment: I guess any flavor would do, just capture the part you want: `/([^/]*)$`

Comment: So then just replace the "/" with nothing and call it a day...

Comment: @TonyHinkle so much backtracking for nothing... Better still leave the `/` to act as an anchor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use brackets in regexp, than you can access by reference \1.

Example (if length not equals to 6 you should update it.):

```
<?php

preg_match('/\/(\d{6})$/', 'http://domain.com/folder/subfolder/123456', $m);
var_dump($m[1]);
```

Result:

```
string(6) "123456"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just match the last characters in the string before the `$` that is not a `/`:

```
([^\/]+)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eK4fP8/1)

Or, use `\w+` and an anchor:

```
(\w+)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eK4fP8/2)